# Посчитайте и выведите в консоль элемент с максимальной длиной. Если элементов с такой длиной несколько, выведите первый

Tags: javascript, массивы

В программе объявлена переменная list, в которую записан массив из строковых значений. Посчитайте и выведите в консоль элемент с максимальной длиной. Если элементов с такой длиной несколько, выведите первый.

Пример значений переменных:
list = ["Груша", "Яблоко"]

Пример результата:
"Яблоко"

Код на JavaScript:

```
 for(let value of list) { 
       let i =1;
       if (value.length >=i) 
          {i++;} 
       else 
           {console.log(value)}
       }
```

Comment: Чел ты сам попытался решить эту задачу?

Comment: Вы хоть скажите на каком языке пытаетесь написать код? (Если вообще пытаетесь)

Comment: @had0uken  на русском языке))

Comment: JS. Код for(let value of list){ let i =1; if (value.length >=i) {i++;} else{console.log(value)} }

Comment: Где ты находишь максимальную длину?

Comment: Переменная i  лишняя скорее всего?

Comment: Элементы нужно сравнивать друг с другом но как это реализовать в коде?

Answer (score 0):

Ну смотри приведу программу на русском языке:

```
массив list = {"Яблоко","Груша"}
переменная МаксимальныйКолвоЭлементов = 0 
переменная цикл =0
ДляКаждого(элемент:list){
МаксимальныйКолвоСимволов = Макс(размер(элемент))
цикл++
}

Вывод << list[цикл]
```

Comment: for (let index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
    console.log(list[index]);
  }
  console.log(list[1]);